# Kafka JoinGroup API not response

Tags: apache-kafka

https://kafka.apache.org/protocol.html

I am reading this document.

I started kafka locally and calling JoinGroup api.
(key = 11, version = 1)

When calling JoinGroup api in Kafka 2.4.1 version
I am getting a response successfully.

However, in the latest version of Kafka (2.7.1, 2.8.0), when calling JoinGroup api,
I get no response (no response at all)

Then after 5 minutes (the default value of max.poll.interval.ms is 300000, so I guess it is this time)

I get a response with error code 25 (UNKNOWN_MEMBER_ID).

I haven't been able to find the cause for several weeks, so I'm asking for help.ㅠㅠ

The request I sent when calling JoinGroup api is as follows.

```
JoinGroup Request (Version: 1) => group_id session_timeout_ms rebalance_timeout_ms member_id protocol_type [protocols] 
  group_id => "test-group1"
  session_timeout_ms => 10 * 1000
  rebalance_timeout_ms => 10 * 1000
  member_id => ""
  protocol_type => "consumer"
  protocols => array count 1
    name => "range"
    metadata => "any data..."
```

**kafka 2.4.1 logs**

[2021-08-03 15:11:05,633] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to rebalance group test-group1 in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 0 (__consumer_offsets-9) (reason: Adding new member hahaha-4b113660-8daf-4941-9d3a-4429b607c175 with group instanceid None) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)

[2021-08-03 15:11:05,640] WARN Failed to parse Consumer Protocol consumer:range of group test-group1. Consumer group coordinator is not aware of the subscribed topics. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupMetadata)

**kafka 2.7.1(2.8.0) logs**

[2021-08-03 15:18:15,454] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Dynamic Member with unknown member id joins group test-group1 in Empty state. Created a new member id hahaha-239b6f13-b96e-4c7e-98f8-ea049aeb759c for this member and add to the group. (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)

[2021-08-03 15:18:15,460] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Preparing to rebalance group test-group1 in state PreparingRebalance with old generation 0 (__consumer_offsets-9) (reason: Adding new member hahaha-239b6f13-b96e-4c7e-98f8-ea049aeb759c with group instance id None) (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)

[2021-08-03 15:23:15,468] INFO [GroupCoordinator 0]: Member hahaha-239b6f13-b96e-4c7e-98f8-ea049aeb759c in group test-group1 has failed, removing it from the group (kafka.coordinator.group.GroupCoordinator)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same error, did you find the explanation?